# When is it safe to call setAnchorPoint: for a CALayer?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, quartz-graphics

I want to set the `anchorPoint` property on a `layer` inside one of my `NSViewController`s.

I've tried to set the `anchorPoint` inside `loadView` and `awakeFromNib`; these both get called the first time the `view` property of my `NSViewController` is accessed. And this is where I am currently setting the `anchorPoint`.

The problem I'm experiencing is that as soon as I add my view controller's `view` as a subview to another view (somewhere on my main window), Cocoa internally calls a private method on `NSView` called `_updateLayerGeometryFromView`, which then overrides my anchorPoint with the default one.

So my question is, what's the earliest point I can set the `anchorPoint` of my `layer` without it being overridden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the AppKit release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKit.html) (as of Mountain Lion; that link will need to be updated when 10.9 comes out):

> - On 10.8, AppKit will control the following properties on a CALayer (both when "layer-hosted" or "layer-backed"): geometryFlipped, bounds, frame (implied), position, **anchorPoint**, transform, shadow*, hidden, filters, and compositingFilter. … Use the appropriate NSView cover methods to change these properties.

I'd try [the `translateOriginToPoint:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/translateOriginToPoint%3a).